# How is farz ghusl done exactly?

Tags: salat, wudu, ghusl

This has been on my mind for a while and I have looked at several explanations but I’m still confused. Are we supposed to wash our private parts first and then the whole body once? Or are we not allowed to touch it during ghusl? Sometimes I am under difficult circumstances and I can’t do the sunnah but I really don’t know how the shorter version works. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me EXACTLY what to do just for farz. Also, not sure if it’s important to know for this but I’m female.

Comment: You ask about fard ghusl and discuss sunnah acts...? How to perform ghusl is easy and explained in several posts.

Comment: I don’t know im just confused. I have watched videos and read posts but I really don’t understand at all

Answer (score 0):

Simple. There are three steps that you should follow in order to perform the fara'id (mandatory steps) of the ghusl.

According to Wikipedia :

> Farā'id of Ghusl (Hanafi Guidelines)
> There are three fard (obligatory) acts. If one of these acts is omitted, it must be returned to and completed before the remaining acts.[9]
>
> 1. Rinsing the inner mouth
> 2. Sniffing water and blowing it out.
> 3. Washing the entire body.
>    [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghusl#Far%C4%81'id_of_Ghusl_(Hanafi_Guidelines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghusl#Far%C4%81%27id_of_Ghusl_(Hanafi_Guidelines))

Washing the body means just pouring water over your body, especially over your private parts so that all of the impurities go away.

Comment: Okay thank you, but do we have to wash it with our hands or not? I personally feel like if I just pour water over that part the impurities won’t go away but I don’t know if that would be allowed. (I know I sound really stupid but im genuinely wondering.)

Comment: :) Just make sure that the impurities go away (it also depends on what kind of impurities it  is ! if you can still see or smell the impurities after using only water, then use your left hand (the top of your left hand, not the whiter part) and). It's just to make sure that all the impurities go away. For example, if the impurity is just urine, then water is enough because it will dilute in the water, but if it's semen, then water *might* not be enough. You can use your left hand. The most important part is just to completely clean yourself from impurities.

Comment: okay, thank you for explaining so did I understand this correctly: the most important thing is removing impurities & washing the body once and if I do use my hand for impurities I don’t have to do wudu afterwards?

Comment: No obviously just do the steps in my answer (whether you use your hands or not) and when you finish your ghusl do a wudu to pray. you don't have to do wudu in your ghusl. wudu is from the sunnah of the ghusl.

Comment: I’m really sorry but now im confused again, you said no but you also said I have to do a wudu after I finish my ghusl. Do I have to do it or not? (I’m still a bit new to everything that’s why i don’t know so many things)

Comment: I think they are trying to say you can do a wudu after you finish the ghusl as wudu is needed for salat and reading Quran. Just do your ghusl and after you finish the ghusl do wudu

Comment: Yes, Usman you got it, thank you for clarifying what I said. dlsj, I meant you do your wudu to pray salat, not for the ghusl.

Comment: okay but I thought after ghusl I don’t have to do wudu? Because ghusl removes major and minor impurity so I don’t understand why I have to do wudu after ghusl

Comment: No, you have to do wudu after ghusl. It doesn’t have to make sense, this is the way of Allah to make sure we humans are clean from impurities to do salat, just imagine what would happen if wudu wasn’t obligatory...

Comment: I don’t want to sound rude but then there wouldn’t really be a difference between the 2 types of ghusl? Because you would have to do wudu either way, whether sunnah or fard. And how about this link? https://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/34913/
Doesn’t that mean that simply being in the water would be enough?

Comment: And I’ve read on so many websites that wudu is not needed after ghusl (except on eid or jumu'ah) so I would just like proof for your statement because I genuinely don’t understand and I’m a little stressed out about this (sorry if I sound rude)

Comment: (You don’t sound rude :)) I’m not 100% sure if the wudu after the ghusl is mandatory but every time you do the wudu you get a reward for it (https://www.assimalhakeem.net/2015/09/14/what-are-the-rewards-of-performing-wudhu/) and it takes less than a minute to do so in my opinion it would better to do the wudu after the ghusl.

Comment: Alright but for me wudu always takes at least 10 minutes so if I do ghusl before that, can I just do face arms head and feet wudu? Or do I have to do sunnah wudu? Sorry for the questions but im new and i really don’t wanna do it wrong

Comment: "And I’ve read on so many websites that wudu is not needed after ghusl". Are you talking about the farz or the sunnah ghusl ? Don’t be stressed about it, it’s not like you’re gonna be punished if you don’t do something...

Comment: I’m not sure but I usually read that ghusl removes all impurities and it’s not necessary to do wudu afterwards. And I don’t know im just a bit stressed because I don’t want my prayers to be invalid

Comment: Do you want to move this conversation to discord or something cuz the comment section isn’t supposed to be used for this ?

Comment: Anyways, I found a good answer to your question if you didn’t already find it : https://www.islamawareness.net/Ghusl/fatwa_wudu_1.html

Comment: thanks for the link I’ll check it out