# Question for salah

Tags: salat

Firstly,does fluid like (white fluid)break your ablution and secondly if it break then would I have to do all my prayers and thirdly does sit bubbles from front also break my ablution during Salah , And the white fluid flow during when I'm praying plz pay attention to this sentence

Answer (score 0):

Maniy (semen) breaks your taharah (state where you are free from impurities) and it also breaks your wudu and salah.

If semen comes out then you have to do the ghusl in order to clean yourself from the impurities (semen). Then you should do your wudu and then you can pray your prayer again.

If you want to do the ghusl see this : https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/69002/45103

And don’t give the white fluid (semen, presumably) flow attention, it might just be shaytan (the devil) trying to make your salah harder to do.